# Cant Delete a Value From HashMap Which is Selected Randomly

Tags: java, swing, hashmap

I prepared a project that is inspired from Trivia Crack.

SporHmap is a HashMap which stores 3 values(questions). In the actionListener method the program gets a random key from the Hashmap and prints questions and the answers to the JLabels and JButtons of the QuestionClass.

The problem here is, I dont want the questions to be repeated. If a question was shown, it should not be showed again. I used ***tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);*** after a value was chosen but it didnt change anything.

```
TriviaLinked tl = new TriviaLinked();
tl.SporHmap.put("Basketbolda 3 adımdan fazla atılan adıma ne denir?","Steps");
tl.SporHmap.put("Hindistan'ın ulusal sporu nedir?","Kriket");
tl.SporHmap.put("Süper Lig'de hakeme kırmızı kart gösteren futbolcu kimdir?","Salih Dursun");

Spor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        QuestionClass q = new QuestionClass();
        q.getQFrame();


        Object[] values = tl.SporHmap.values().toArray();
        String randomValue = (String)values[r.nextInt(values.length)];



        if(tl.SporHmap.get("Hindistan'ın ulusal sporu nedir?").equals(randomValue)){
            q.label.setText("Hindistan'ın ulusal sporu nedir?");
            q.answer1.setText("Kriket");
            q.answer2.setText("Beyzbol");
            q.answer3.setText("Hokey");
            q.answer4.setText("Futbol");

            tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);


            q.answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "True Answer");
                    score.setText("Score: "+scr++);

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();

                    Spor.doClick();


                }
            });
            q.answer3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");
                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");


                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");


                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });



        }



        else if(tl.SporHmap.get("Basketbolda 3 adımdan fazla atılan adıma ne denir?").equals(randomValue)){
            q.label.setText("Basketbolda 3 adımdan fazla atılan adıma ne denir?");
            q.answer1.setText("Serbest atış");
            q.answer2.setText("Dışarı çıkış");
            q.answer3.setText("Steps");
            q.answer4.setText("Faul");

            tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);
            q.answer3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "True Answer");
                    score.setText("Score: "+scr++);

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
}
 });

        }
        else if(tl.SporHmap.get("Süper Lig'de hakeme kırmızı kart gösteren futbolcu kimdir?").equals(randomValue)){
            q.label.setText("Süper Lig'de hakeme kırmızı kart gösteren futbolcu kimdir?");
            q.answer1.setText("Erkan Zengin");
            q.answer2.setText("Özer Hurmacı");
            q.answer3.setText("Salih Dursun");
            q.answer4.setText("Aykut Demir");

            tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);

            q.answer3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "True Answer");
                    score.setText("Score: "+scr++);

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });
            q.answer1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");

                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();

                }
            });
            q.answer2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");


                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });

            q.answer4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");


                    q.getQFrame().dispose();
                    Spor.doClick();
                }
            });

        }

    }
});
```

Here is my QuestionClass class:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class QuestionClass {
public JLabel label,label1;
public JFrame questionFrame;
public JButton answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4;

public QuestionClass() {
    questionFrame = new JFrame();
    questionFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(questionFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    questionFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    questionFrame.setSize(700, 350);
    questionFrame.setVisible(true);
    questionFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    label = new JLabel("");
    questionFrame.add(label);
    label1 = new JLabel("");
    questionFrame.add(label1);
    answer1 = new JButton("");
    questionFrame.add(answer1);
    answer2 = new JButton("");
    questionFrame.add(answer2);
    answer3 = new JButton("");
    questionFrame.add(answer3);
    answer4 = new JButton("");
    questionFrame.add(answer4);
}

public JFrame getQFrame() {
    return questionFrame;
}
}
```

Comment: I take that as "problem solved". Thanks for the quick accept! So, what was the problem?

Comment: I changed **tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);** with **tl.SporHmap.remove("Hindistan'ın ulusal sporu nedir?");** and it worked. It doesnt seem so logical but there is no problem yet. Also, i have to change all the **remove(randomValue)** parts with **remove(....)**.

Comment: Thats ... strange. But whatever. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You approach is correct:  after showing a question; delete it from the map.

In other words: just fill your map with enough questions to look at; select them randomly; and after asking a question, [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) the corresponding key from your map.

But it seems that you are calling

```
 tl.SporHmap.remove(randomValue);
```

Only for **one** of your potential cases. There should **not** be a condition for that remove. You randomly select a question, and then you remove it!

Beyond that: your "object" model isn't too good. There is no point in having that map, but to then have if/elses for the choices! Instead: you could create a QuizzQuestion class, and a QuizzQuestion has:

- The question text itself
- The correct answer
- The other (wrong) answers

Using that class, you can put **all** values that belong together into such a QuizzQuestion object.

And then you also don't need a Map; just a `List<QuizzQuestion>` objects will do!

Given your comment: basically, these could be possible root causes for your problem:

- As said; you don't `remove` for all possible cases
- You "re-init" your HashMap accidentally (meaning: you actually remove the value; but you re-create or re-populate the whole map afterwards again)
- A conceptual error: you assume that your program should remember its last state; so that when you close the program and start afresh; it should not show questions shown in a previous run. That would be a misconception on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My teacher wanted me to combine Linked Lists and Hashmaps. There could be a better model as you defined. By the way, i didnt shared all the code. There is an if case for all keys of the hashmap.

Comment: i edited my code and shared a larger part of it. I would be appreciated if you take a look at it.

Comment: Gnarf. You brought back all those useless empty lines that just make it harder to read. I will see what I can do. But don't expect too much; it is already late here. But if I dont find anything, and you dont hear anything else, I might check tomorrow. And hint: you might want to look into using a **debugger** ;-)